# Django queryset- Filter by not in list

Tags: django, django-queryset, python-2.x

I have Dog model which has name and color, and i have list of tuples that contains (name, color) of dogs that I want to exclude.
How can I achieve a queryset that would be filter dogs that not exist in that list?

```
class Dog(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255)

Dog.objects.all()
>> [<Dog: name='Lucky', color='Brown'>, <Dog: name='Lucky', color='White'>, <Dog: name='Maple', color='Brown'> ,<Dog: name='Maple', color='Black'>, <Dog: name='Maple', color='White'>]

_list = [('Maple', 'White'), ('Lucky', 'Brown')]
```

What im looking for is something like that:

```
Dog.objects.custom_exclude(_list)

>> [<Dog: name='Lucky', color='White'>, <Dog: name='Maple', color='Brown'> ,<Dog: name='Maple', color='Black'>]
```

Comment: try Dog.objects.extra(where=['(name, color) not in %s' % list])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

from django.db.models import Q

exclude_params = reduce(operator.or_, [Q(name=name, color=color) for name, color in list])
Dog.objects.exclude(exclude_params)
```